# res.render can't get result parameter after querying mysql in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am working on a node app with express. But i met a very strange bug.

```
router.post('/search', function (req, res, next) {
  var key = req.body.search;
  if(key.length>0) {
    connection.query('select * from patient where name=?', [key], function(err, result) {
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(result);  
      res.render('searchPage', {
        name: "Alex",
        birthday: result.Birthday,
        sex: result.sex,
        symptom: result.Symptom,
        contact: result.Contact,
      });
    })
  }
})
```

After i post something to do a search, i got something in my command line.

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: '1',
    Name: 'Alex',
    Birthday: null,
    sex: null,
    Sympton: null,
    Contact: '13719483934' } ]
```

But i got nothing in my `searchPage` html page except the string `ALex` i past to my jade file. It seems like my jade file can get variable value properly but the `result` param fails inside res.render(). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array (looking at docs it always is). So you should use use the first element in this case like this (from: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

```
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, 
  fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
      console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
 });
```

Comment: It is the solution.  Thank you.